# Optimal fit of image to display

Tags: javascript, display

Is there a way that css/html5 can fit an image optimally to a viewport such that no cropping will occur?

I would appreciate a solution above.  Here's how it might be done in code:

If the aspect ratio of the image (H/W) is larger than the display, then the image css would be height:100%, width:auto;

If the aspect ratio of the image (H/W) is smaller than the display, then the image css would be height:auto, width:100%

This seems like a lot of work, is there a simpler solution?

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works for you.  the `vh` unit means viewport height.

```
.that-image {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
}
```

There is a corresponding unit for width, `vw`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set is as your div background and give this styles

```html
    <div class='my-image.jpg'></div>
```

```css
    .my-image {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        text-align: center;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/457882/pexels-photo-457882.jpeg");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I went with to avoid distorting the image aspect ratio:

```
function fitImage() { // Optimally fit an image to the viewport
    var width = $(this).width();    // Current image width
    var height = $(this).height();  // Current image height 

    var viewportHeight = $(window).height(); // The viewport height/width
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width(); 

    var aspectImage = parseFloat(height)/parseFloat(width); // Need Floating point
    var aspectViewport = parseFloat(viewportHeight)/parseFloat(viewportWidth);

    if (aspectImage > aspectViewport) { // height:100%;width:auto;
        $(this).width("auto"); // Image aspect ratio > Viewport 
        $(this).height("100%");
    } else { // height:auto;width:100%
        $(this).width("100%"); // Image aspect ration <= Viewport
        $(this).height("auto");
    }

}
```